# How to loop and display MySQL dates into FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, python, fullcalendar, bottle

I am using python with bottle framework and JavaScript, and I want to display fetched MySQL dates into FullCalender. I am successfully fetching the data from MySQL, as shown below, but the problem is when I pass the value "dates" to the "start" key, my expectation was to see all the dates in the Callendar, but instead, I am only getting the last date.

**Here is my JavaScript code:**

```
<script>
    let calendarElement = document.querySelector("#calendar");
    fetch('/api-fetch-booking_data')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        data.booking_dates.forEach(element => {
            let dates = element.avalable_dates
            console.log(dates);                
            let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElement, {
                
                events: [
                    {
                        start: dates,
                    }
                ]
            
            });
        calendar.render();
        })
    })
</script>
```

**These are the dates fetched from MySQL:**

[image]

**This is the UI, as you can see I am only getting the "2022-06-30" date:**

[image]

I have seen that you could do a for loop like this using flask:
[image]

but I really don't know how and even if it is bossible to do it with bottle. Hope someone will help me up with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: read full documentation for bottle - it can also use `for`-loops in template. But question is if you use template in your code. It seems you use some JavaScript code `FullCalendar` and it may means you have to do all in JavaScript. Maybe you have to create `events: [{start: dates[0]}, {start: dates[1]}, ... ]` - and this need only JavaScript code, not Python.

Comment: you should show how you format JSON data before you send to browser.

Comment: @furas I am using json.dumps() on python, and I also get JSON after fetch request. And my question is, can one use bottle for-loops on JavaScript? I know how to do it in HTML but not JS.

Also, the idea for me is to use a for-loop so I can display all the available dates in the database. This means, that if I add a new time in the DB, it should automatically display on the calendar.

Comment: you can't use `bottle`/`python` `for`-loop in `JavaScript` - `JavaScript` has own `for`-loop. And as for me you try to create many FullCalendars - every date put in separated `FullCalendar` but every `FullCalendar` use the same `div` to display it - and finally you see only last FullCalendar with last date. But you should use single `FullCalendar` and send all data to this single `FullCalendar` - I added full working example in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read full documentation for bottle then you should find information how to use `for`-loops in template in `bottle`.

But you send data to JavaScript library `FullCalendar` and you have to do all in JavaScript.

You may have to create

```
events: [{start: dates[0]}, {start: dates[1]}, ... ]
```

and this need only JavaScript code, not Python.

---

**EDIT:**

See documentation for events https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: [
    {
      title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2010-01-01'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event2',
      start  : '2010-01-05',
      end    : '2010-01-07'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event3',
      start  : '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
      allDay : false // will make the time show
    }
  ]
});
```

But it seems it can get also `JSON` data which you can format in Python before sending to browser. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: '/link/to/bottle/function'
});
```

and this function would have to return JSON with

```
[
    {
      title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2010-01-01'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event2',
      start  : '2010-01-05',
      end    : '2010-01-07'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event3',
      start  : '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
      allDay : false // will make the time show
    }
  ]
```

---

It seems you already send JSON but you would have to set it as

```
events: dates
```

and in dates you would have to send data formatted as

```
[
    {
      title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2010-01-01'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event2',
      start  : '2010-01-05',
      end    : '2010-01-07'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event3',
      start  : '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
      allDay : false // will make the time show
    }
  ]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code.

It uses only one `FullCalendar` in `JavaScript` and it puts all dates from bottle in this `FullCalendar`.

Your code uses `forEach` so it creates many `FullCalendar` - and it puts every date in separated `FullCalendar`. But all `FullCalendar` use the same `<div id='calendar'>` so finally you see only last `FullCalendar` with last date.

```py
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
def hello():
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.min.js'></script>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let calendarElement = document.querySelector("#calendar");
    fetch('/api-fetch-booking_data')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElement, {
             events: data
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
});
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
'''

@route('/api-fetch-booking_data')
def data():
    import json

    return json.dumps([
                {
                  "start": "2022-05-01",
                  "title": "Previous month"
                },
                {
                  "start": "2022-06-01",
                  "title": "Current month"
                },
                {
                  "start": "2022-06-20",
                  "title": "Today"
                }
            ])

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

And the same with `events: url` instead of `fetch()`

**EDIT:** I added button `Refetch Events` which reads new data from bottle. In bottle I use random to create random day to see difference.
When `FullCalendar` fetch data from bottle then it automatically adds dates `start`, `end` to url `/api-fetch-booking_data` so `bottle` could send only events in this range. `FullCalendar` automatically fetch new events when you change month.

```py
from bottle import route, request, run

@route('/')
def hello():
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.min.js'></script>

<script>
var calendar = "";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let calendarElement = document.querySelector("#calendar");
    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElement, {
         events: '/api-fetch-booking_data'
    });
    calendar.render();
});
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="calendar.refetchEvents()">Refetch Events</button><br>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
'''

@route('/api-fetch-booking_data')
def data():
    import json
    import random

    print('start:', request.query.get('start'))
    print('end  :', request.query.get('end'))

    return json.dumps([
                {
                  "start": "2022-05-01",
                  "title": "Previous month"
                },
                {
                  "start": "2022-06-01",
                  "title": "Current month"
                },
                {
                  "start": f"2022-06-{random.randint(1,30):02}",
                  "title": "Random day"
                },
                {
                  "start": "2022-06-20",
                  "title": "Today"
                }
            ])

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: I added example which use `events: url`. I also added button to reload events from bottle. In bottle I use `random` to see different event in every reload. I see it automatically sends date `start`, `end` so bottle could send dates only in this range. It also automatically reload events when you change month.

Comment: thank you so much, both suggestions work pretty well! I appreciate your time!